# Взаимное использование заголовков c++

Tags: c++

Проблема такая, я не могу использовать вот так:

```
// klass1.hpp
#ifndef KLASS1_HPP
#define KLASS1_HPP

#include "klass2.hpp"

class klass1
{
public:
    klass1()
    {
        auto klass_2 = klass2(this);
        klass_2.test();
    }

    static int version = 2;
    int sd = 1;
};

#endif

//klass2.hpp

#ifndef KLASS_HPP
#define KLASS_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "klass1.hpp"

class klass2
{
public:
    klass1* klass_1;
    explicit klass2(klass1 klass)
    {
        klass_1 = klass;
    }

    void test()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi: " << klass1::version << " << " << klass_1->sd << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы не можете сделать так:

```
static int version = 2;
```

Если используете 17 стандард, то, впринципе можете эту переменную заинлайнить, иначе присваивайте значение в конструкторе

Во-вторых,выносите реализацию в файлы `.cpp` - это избавит вас от проблем с включением в хидеры всего что ни попадя

В-третьих, в хидерах используйте предекларацию. Тобишь когда в вашем классе используются ссылки или указатели на объекты других классов, то не нужно включать соответствующие `include` просто пометьте `class MyClass;`. Важно помнить, что это работает только для объектов (переменных класса), доступ к которых осуществляется по указателями и ссылками. Также это допустимо, если происходит передача по значению в методах класса.

Comment: 1;2 - я сделал лишь пример.
3 - если я не использую include, а просто class klass1, то каким образом мне это должно помочь?

Comment: @legasov без 1,2 - никак не поможет

Comment: т.е вы предлагаете так: 
https://pastebin.com/NGng6nEp

Comment: @legasov вроде того

Comment: без include все-таки не обошлось, конечный вариант получился таким: https://pastebin.com/K8x2z69d

Comment: @legasov в данном случае совершенно не нужно вставлять `include` ни в один из хидеров - нужно это сделать только в `cpp` файлах

Comment: вы совершенно верно подметили, благодарю

Comment: кстати, если данный класс, например klass1, находится в каком либо namespace, то как его записать? class name_space::klass1; ?

Comment: @legasov до 17-ого можно было записать только так: `namespace my_namespace { class my_class; }`